# Is there any documentation on the settings file used by libspotify?

Tags: spotify

Libspotify stores settings in a file called settings. Now, it seems that it discards anything that isn't used by the Spotify client itself, for example "g_sett_high_bitrate":1 is kept at sp_session_logout, while "bitrate":2 is removed from the file.

Is there any documentation at all for these settings? Or will I just have to make my own separate settings file (seems kinda silly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything inside the settings and caches folders is owned by libSpotify, and may be deleted or altered at any time. For your own application's settings, use a separate file.